# Wordpress user profile display name - change from selectbox to textbox

Tags: php, wordpress, field, profile

Im trying to change the user profile "Display name publicly as" from a select box to a textbox. Any ideas on how this can be done? Couldnt find anything all all.

Answer (score 0):

Two way to solve it. You edit the wordpress core file, which is not a good way. Or you can add an extra field on profile box using wordpress hook.

I am giving you the first way:

Go to wp-admin/user-edit.php

Open the file. Then find

```
<td>
    <select name="display_name" id="display_name">
    <?php
        $public_display = array();
        $public_display['display_nickname']  = $profileuser->nickname;
        $public_display['display_username']  = $profileuser->user_login;

        if ( !empty($profileuser->first_name) )
            $public_display['display_firstname'] = $profileuser->first_name;

        if ( !empty($profileuser->last_name) )
            $public_display['display_lastname'] = $profileuser->last_name;

        if ( !empty($profileuser->first_name) && !empty($profileuser->last_name) ) {
            $public_display['display_firstlast'] = $profileuser->first_name . ' ' . $profileuser->last_name;
            $public_display['display_lastfirst'] = $profileuser->last_name . ' ' . $profileuser->first_name;
        }

        if ( !in_array( $profileuser->display_name, $public_display ) ) // Only add this if it isn't duplicated elsewhere
            $public_display = array( 'display_displayname' => $profileuser->display_name ) + $public_display;

        $public_display = array_map( 'trim', $public_display );
        $public_display = array_unique( $public_display );

        foreach ( $public_display as $id => $item ) {
    ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $id; ?>"<?php selected( $profileuser->display_name, $item ); ?>><?php echo $item; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Change it with

```
<th><label for="display_name"><?php _e('Display name publicly as'); ?> </label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->display_name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
```

But still this is not a good solution.

Comment: Edit core is not an option. Will add an extra field then. thanks

Comment: There is no way to hide the "Display name publicly as" using hook. All you can do is add another custom field.

Comment: Thanks Adil. Ended up using a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and used a bit of javascript to solve it. Wordpress allows you to set the `display_name` field to anything you want, so you can use the following script (in your theme's `functions.php` file) to convert the select to a text field.

```
function change_display_name_to_textfield() {
  echo "><div>"; // don't remove '>'
  ?>
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) { 
      // replace display_name select with input
      $('select#display_name').after( '<input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" value="' + $('#display_name').val() + '" class="regular-text">' ).remove();
    })
  </script>
  <?php
  echo "</div"; // don't add '>'
}

// hook into new user and edit user pages
add_action( "user_new_form_tag", "change_display_name_to_textfield" );
add_action( "user_edit_form_tag", "change_display_name_to_textfield" );
```

Note the weird use of opening/closing tags. This is because those particular hooks execute just before the end of the opening form tag. So you need to close the form tag, print your script, then print a final tag *without* closing it.

Answer (score 0):

For admin user edit pages, I found one of the easiest way:

```
add_action( 'personal_options', 'rm_personal_options' );
function rm_personal_options($profileuser){
    if( !is_admin() ) return; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        //$("input#nickname").parent().parent().hide();
        $("select#display_name").replaceWith(function(){
            return '<input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" value="'+$(this).val()+'" class="regular-text" style="width:25em" />';
        });
    });
</script>
    <?php
}
```

Simply paste it into the functions.php of the theme file :)